# Python equivalent for PHP's array_push?

Tags: python, arrays, list, append, implode

i just discovered python and wonder is there a way to do  php like implode and array_pus() 
if i got this code

```
for row in result:
nickname = row[0]
scor = row[1]
print (row)
```

which return this

```
('100000481613163', 6)
('100001018323774', 1)
('bobonete', 1)
('edi', 1)
('jon', 1)
```

i want to access them outsite the loop into a variable like this

```
  (100000481613163, 6), (100001018323774, 1), (bobonete, 1), (edi, 1), (jon, 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well let us give you a clear explanation.
You can use a list, a list is declared with myList = [].
List's has build-in properties like append and pop.
If you need pairs inside lists you can use tuples, tuples are declared like
mu Tuple = (x,y). The code bellow shows an example.

```
list = []
list.append(('ab','cd'))
list.append(('de','fg'))

print(list)
[('ab','cd'),('de','fg')]
```